# GAE Datastore put() not working properly

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to ad a record of Transaction kind and then update the value of balance in User entity.
Here is the code :

```
class Transaction(db.Model):
user_ID = db.IntegerProperty(required = True)
amount = db.FloatProperty(default = 0.0)
remark = db.StringProperty(required = True)
proof = db.IntegerProperty(required = True)
time = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)

@classmethod
def add(cls,userID,amount,remark,proof):
    user = User.get_by_id(int(userID))
    logging.debug("amount : " + str(amount) + " before adding balance : " + str(user.balance))
    user.balance += amount
    logging.debug("after adding balance : " + str(user.balance))
    user.put()
    logging.debug("after putting balance : " + str( User.get_by_id(userID).balance ))
    t = cls(user_ID=userID,amount=amount,remark=remark,proof=proof)
    t.put()
```

LOG :

D 2014-12-19 00:53:23.413 amount : 0.47 before adding balance : 0.0

D 2014-12-19 00:53:23.413 after adding balance : 0.47

D 2014-12-19 00:53:23.462 after putting balance : 0.47

The logs are proper but This is not working as it should.

It should :

1. Ad a record of Transaction and
2. Update the balance value of User

but instead I am getting weird result:

1. Transaction record is added
   [image]
2. User's balance is not updated.
   [image]

Comment: All Datastore operations in a transaction must operate on entities in the same entity group. Why not use NDB and why nog reference the user using a key property.

Comment: @voscausa I haven't used transactions, it is normal operation.

Comment: Data in the viewer may be out of date due to eventual consistancy.  Get the record by id to check it's true state.  And all of this should be in a transanction.  One of the two put's could fail, and putting these operations will mean all succeed or all fail.

Comment: somewhere in the code i was repudiating balance to old value. PROBLEM SOLVED.